# Any function to load the data of 2 share point lists to a single gallery in power apps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I'm developing a new application which takes survey of the users. In my gallery i have 2 labels(it requires Question and Comments), 1 slider(Rating value). Now, to one label i need data from gallery's data source. To the other label and slider i need data present in another share point list. How can I get the data present in two different lists to single gallery of power app?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have two lists (let's call them `Questions` and `Comments`). In your gallery, you show the comments with a slider, and you want to show the corresponding question title on that. If this is the case, then there are two cases:

1. If in the Comments list you have a column of type 'Look up (information already on this site)', then you can access the value of the other list directly:

   `ThisItem.LookUpColumnName.Value`
2. If you don't have a lookup column, then you need some way to correlate the item from the comments list with the corresponding question. This is usually done with a column that holds the id of the item on the other list. If you have such a column, then you can use a LookUp expression in the label:

   `LookUp(Questions, ID = ThisItem.IdQuestion, Title)`

Hope this helps!